# Is it possible to define a custom numbering style in Pages?

Tags: catalina, pages, iwork, formatting

I would like to cite some articles, books. The standard form is to use square brackets, but Pages these are not within Pages numbering styles. I want to achieve:

[1] 1st source

[2] 2nd source

.

.

.

[n] n source

Is it possible to create a completely new style? I know that I can redefined style in the terms of spacing, but I have not find an option to define own "bullet buttons".

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not.
While you can indeed define custom *bullet* styles, you cannot modify the predefined numbering styles or add a new numbering style.

You can use Apple's feedback form to send a feature request.

https://www.apple.com/feedback/pages.html

Comment: I thought as much. I think I have found some "tricks" in terminal overriding the iWork setting, but it was not exactly numbering. So, I was thinking whether it may be used to this feature adjustment. I submitted the feature request though.

Comment: I wonder if after almost two years that feature has been eventually added. It seems not to me but I would like to ask to a broader audience.